# How to customize a title page using the Ilmenau theme?

Tags: beamer, themes

I want to display my title page in beamer as described in the figure below.
I don't want that the table of content figure in the header. Moreover, I can't display all the information in the title page; the date and the supervisor.
How I can delete the space to display all information. The code is below :

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]   
   {beamer}
  \usepackage[french]{babel}
  \usepackage{pifont}
  \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
  \definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
  \definecolor{charcoal}{RGB}{34,34,34}
  %Packages
  \usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree}%Beamer theme v 2.2
  \usepackage{beamerthemebars}
  \usepackage{ifthen}
  \usepackage{multimedia}
  \mode<presentation>
  %Theme commands
  \usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
  % \setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}
  \usetheme{Ilmenau}% Beamer theme v 3.0
 \useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles  on top
 \usefonttheme{serif}
 \useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
 \setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
 \setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
 \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
 %
 \newcommand*\oldmacro{}%Pages at the bottom right corner
 \let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
 \renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
 \oldmacro\hfill%
\insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
% \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\title[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\author[Mr. xxxxxxxx]{Pr\'{e}sent\'{e}e par: \textbf{Mr. xxxxxxxxxx}}
\institute[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]{ }
\date{02/2017}
\begin{document}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{1cm}
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=1cm, height = 0.95cm]{logoUni.jpg}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{9cm}
 \centering
 {\textbf{\textcolor{black}{
 \fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont {Minist\`{e}re de l'Enseignement  Sup\'{e}rieur et de la Recherche Scientifique \\
 Universit\'{e} Abderrahmane Mira de B\'{e}jaia, Facult\'{e} des Sciences Exactes\\
 Unit\'{e} de Recherche LaMOS}
 }}}
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{2cm}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=2cm, height = 0.90cm]{logo.png}
 \end{column}
\end{columns}
\vspace{1cm}
 \center {SOUTENANCE D'UNE TH\`{E}SE DE DOCTORAT EN MATH\'{E}MATIQUES  APPLIQU\'{E}ES}
  \titlepage
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Table of Contents}
  \small \tableofcontents
  \end{frame}
  \section{A}
  \subsection{AA}
  \begin{frame}A\end{frame}
   \subsection{AA}
  \begin{frame}A\end{frame}
  \section{B}
  \subsection{BA}
  \begin{frame}B\end{frame}
  \subsection{BB}
  \begin{frame}B\end{frame}
  \subsection{BC}
  \begin{frame}B\end{frame}
  \begin{frame}B\end{frame}
  \begin{frame}B\end{frame}
  \section{C}
  \subsection{CA}
  \begin{frame}C\end{frame}
  \subsection{CB}
  \begin{frame}C\end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following code is really just a dirty hack - to do it the right way, one would define a custom title page template for beamer. The most important things:

- all content has be inside a frame environment. Otherwise the vertical orientation will be wrong and framenumbers will do crazy things.
- some beamer options were deprecated, I replaced them by new syntax as told by the various warnings they caused.
- top alignment of the columns can be done with `T`
- removing information from head/footline normally requires to redefine them, but if the font colour matches the background colour the content is invisible.

---

```
\documentclass[t,compress,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\definecolor{charcoal}{RGB}{34,34,34}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\useoutertheme{tree}
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}

\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}

\newcommand*\oldmacro{}
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
    \oldmacro\hfill%
    \insertframenumber\,%
}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\title[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\author[Mr. xxxxxxxx]{Pr\'{e}sent\'{e}e par: \textbf{Mr. xxxxxxxxxx}\\
Encadre\'{e}e par: Professeur}
\institute[xxxxxxxxxxsdxxxxxxxxxxxx]{ }
\date{02/2017}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=structure.fg!75!black}
\begin{frame}
    \vskip0.5cm
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{1cm}
            \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{9cm}
            \bfseries
            \color{black}
            \fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont 
            \centering
                Minist\`{e}re de l'Enseignement  Sup\'{e}rieur et de la Recherche Scientifique \\
                Universit\'{e} Abderrahmane Mira de B\'{e}jaia, Facult\'{e} des Sciences Exactes\\
                Unit\'{e} de Recherche LaMOS
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{2cm}
            \includegraphics[width=2cm, height = 0.90cm]{example-image}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \begin{center}
        SOUTENANCE D'UNE TH\`{E}SE DE DOCTORAT EN MATH\'{E}MATIQUES  APPLIQU\'{E}ES
    \end{center}
    \vskip-1cm
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
}

  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Table of Contents}
  \small \tableofcontents
  \end{frame}
  \section{A}
  \subsection{AA}
  \begin{frame}A\end{frame}
   \subsection{AA}
  \begin{frame}A\end{frame}
  \section{B}
  \subsection{BA}
  \begin{frame}B\end{frame}
  \subsection{BB}
  \begin{frame}B\end{frame}
  \subsection{BC}
  \begin{frame}B\end{frame}
  \begin{frame}B\end{frame}
  \begin{frame}B\end{frame}
  \section{C}
  \subsection{CA}
  \begin{frame}C\end{frame}
  \subsection{CB}
  \begin{frame}C\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I would  keep the header. I want only remove the content element. Anoteher question is : how to rezise the content elements in the header, because I have a long titles of sections.

Comment: @SamFaith For long section names, use `\section[short version]{long version}`